# How to implement an Ember Simple Auth using an external redirect

Tags: ember.js, saml, adfs, ember-simple-auth

Here's my workflow.

1. User presses a login button.
2. User is redirected to the API which redirects to a login page on a third party site (ADFS SAML).
3. User authenticates there, is returned to the API which decodes the response, creates a user and a JWT token (both stored in a datastore), and then redirects the user to Ember with a `?token=` query parameter.

What I'd like to do is work this in to a custom `ember-simple-auth` `authenticator` (and `authorizer`?) in order to take advantage of the niceness of session and Authorization headers from there on.

Currently I've hacked an authenticator to do just the redirect to the identity provider. The rest of the API workflow is working. And I'm catching the token in a route on the way back and populating a User resource via a call to the database. But I feel that I'm heading down the wrong (and the long) path.

Any thoughts? Is this something that `ember-simple-auth-token` is designed for?

Comment: Did you had a look at [`OAuth2ImplicitGrantCallbackMixin`](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/OAuth2ImplicitGrantCallbackMixin.html) provided by ember-simple-auth? I guess you need to customize it a little bit cause it expects an `access_token` query param as defined by RFC 6749: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2.2 But that should be a simple change.

Comment: Thanks @jelhan I've changed my `token` parameter to `access_token` and roughed that in to my login route which is where I am triggering the initial jump like so. I can't see any differences yet. I'll continue to work through the implicit grant workflow. I hadn't considered it because I thought my case wasn't OAuth2. Do you think it is?
```export default Route.extend(OAuth2ImplicitGrantCallbackMixin, {
  authenticator: "authenticator:custom",
```

Comment: ADFS Supports OAuth2! I'll implement this next week and will ask my boss if I can open source it. Probably it's best to also use torii because of the security vulnerability if you load external resources on the redirection target.

Comment: Thanks @Lux I think that I have to use the SAML workflow. I'm not sure that OAuth2 is enabled at the provider. Is it just something that is _always on_?

Comment: I think you can disable it but it's enabled by default and also recommended by MS

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in last month. what i did was

1. click the login
2. redirect to the adfs
3. adfs login success-> redirect to my backend
4. backend generate a sso temp token with access token details which is
   already there and only valid for 2 minutes.
5. backend redirect web with a GET with params of sso temp token
6. frontend take the params of sso temp token and make another post
   ajax request to backend
7. Api will validate sso temp token and provide details ( access
   token and refresh token ) to the user
8. read response data for the post request in 6 and update on ember
   simple auth service using **authenticate** interface  ( you can
   customize this using custom authenticator )

here is the custom authenticator class

```
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';
import {isEmpty} from '@ember/utils';
export default Base.extend({
  authenticate(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if(data.access_token!=null){
        resolve({
          scope: data.scope,
          access_token: data.access_token,
        });
      }else{
        reject();
      }  })

    },

    restore(data) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!isEmpty(data.access_token)) {
          resolve(data);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    },

  });
```

i have created a route to handle in the frontend to get the token which is sent by backend. so the route takes sso token by a get param ( cause backend cannot do a post to emberapp) so when the route triggers i catch the param in route and do a post method again to validate the token.

we are using redis generated tokens. so since this question is asked about the emberjs i illustrated the answer to support you on frontend. i have illustrate the concept as well to show what you need to do. so its up to you to dig up and find more about it. like how to create temporary JWT token, how to validate it, how to redirect to you to your backend with claims from the adfs and etc. i think i provide answer to the initial question you asked which is 
"How to implement an Ember Simple Auth using an external redirect"

Comment: That's close to where I am up to. I didn't do step 6/7 but that's a good idea. Would you be able to share your `authenticators/custom` and `config/environment`? And what handles the request to the backend for the tokens? Is that a route? Could we see that too please? The SSO temporary token. I've created a JWT token. What are your tokens?